# How do I get the numbers out of this piece of data?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, urllib, elementtree

I've been given an assignment where I have to extract the numbers out of [this xml file](https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/comments_42.xml) and then sum them up. The problem is I'm getting an attribute error when I try to do a for loop to get at the data:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Here's my code so far:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = raw_input('Enter location: ')
print 'Retrieving', url
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = tree.findall('.//count')
print 'Count:', len(lst)
for item in lst:
    print 'name', item.find('count').text
```

I should be extracting text from inside the count tag:

```
<comment>
  <name>Matthias</name>
  <count>97</count>
</comment>
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Beautiful Soup. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

It makes parsing xml files very easy

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)  # It seems that your data variable holds the xml
for tag in soup.find_all('count'):
    print tag.get_text()
```

Comment: This is what I get when I  run your code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Asif/Desktop/socket file/geoxmlpapa.py", line 19, in <module>
    for tag in soup.find_all('count'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. I got the nonetype object error doing it the original way as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried my code and it succeeded!

```
   import urllib
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

   url = raw_input('Enter location: ')
   print 'Retrieving', url
   uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
   data = uh.read()
   print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
   tree = ET.fromstring(data)
   lst = tree.findall('.//count')
   print 'Count:', len(lst)
   total = 0
   for comment in tree.findall("./comments/comment"):
       total += int(comment.find('count').text)
   print total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_4772.xml'
print ('Retrieving', url)
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
counts = tree.findall('.//count')
print ('Count',len(counts))
total=0
for item in counts:
    element=item.text
    total+=int(element)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

A.K. like Gabor Erdos said. BS4 is much better, but if you want to use ElementTree:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_208135.xml'
tresc = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(tresc)

wartosci = tree.findall('.//count')
sum = 0
count = 0

for item in wartosci:
    x = int(item.text)
    sum = sum + x
    count = count + 1

print('Retrieving', url)
print('Retrieving'), len(tresc), 'characters'
print('Count: ', count)
print('Sum: ', sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3, this no-hassle code should work just fine for your assignment:

```
import urllib.request 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = input ("Enter url: ")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url)).read() 

tree = ET.fromstring(response)
data = tree.findall('.//count')

print (sum( [ int(i.text) for i in data ] )) #int before sum before print
```